# Epplus Create Excel with TFS Connection

Tags: .net, tfs, azure-devops, epplus

Is there a way to create an Excel using Epplus which connects to TFS Server project collection programmatically? I wanted to create an Excel programmatically and use it to connect it to TFS.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Excel with Epplus in .Net (C#) and connect to TFS with TFS SDK, you can download these NuGet packages:

[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client/)

[Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/)

[Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/)

All the DLL's also stored in the following location, you can take them and use in your project:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio {Visual Studio Version}\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer"
```

A good tutorial on how to use the SDK you can find [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2011/05/18/tfs-api-index-parts-1-to-37/).

In addition, you can connect TFS with Rest API from your code, you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1) about it.

Comment: The link in `A good tutorial on how to use the SDK you can find here.` seems doesn't work, could you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Epplus can write out a macro within the Excel .

Macro can b used to control the areapath and server url of TFS

Have a look into .https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/teams_wit_tools/2007/03/14/how-to-invoke-tfs-add-in-controls-from-macro-code/